# Displaying GPS data with different colors in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot below mentioned figure. I can use different colors for data points but how can i put arrow heads to them like in a figure ?. 
I am using below mentioned statement. Thanks

```
     plot(type ="o",c, d, xlab="longitude",ylab="latitude", main ="Path", col = 1:3);
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some data for a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce the plot by using geom_segment from ggplot2. 
The code below shows an example using random points:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rpois(10, 5), y = rpois(10, 5), group = 1:10)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(group)))
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(x, n=-1), NA),
                          yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), tail(y, n = 1))),
                      arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
g <- g + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + xlab("longitude") + ylab("latitude") 
g
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Good day !

Comment: I am getting this error : Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (464): xend, yend, x, y, colour
I am using my data, df <- data.frame(c, d , group = 1:length(c))